# .htaccess 301 Redirect Appending Query's to End of URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I am hoping someone can help with an unusual situation.

I have one main rewrite rule in place in my httpd.conf file which handles all of our dynamic content. The rule looks like this and works fine:

RewriteRule ^(.*)(/.*/d/[^.]*)$ /category/refine.cgi\?\&a\=$2

The problem I have is that when I try to use .htaccess to create a simple 301 redirect, the query parameters are automatically appended to the end of the URL's so the final result looks like this:

http://www.example.com/category/page.html**?&a=/category/subcategory/something/d/page/**

Notice that the query string is appended to the URL when using .htaccess to create a 301 redirect.

I have solution for this on a case-by-case basis, but it's not practical to create a new rule each time I want to do a simple 301 redirect.

So, I am wondering if I can edit my "main rule" in any way so that when .htaccess is used to create redirects, the query parameters are not appended to the target URL.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please provide your complete .htaccess here.

Comment: The .htaccess only contains straightforward 301 redirects. The rewriting takes place in the httpd.conf file and the rewrite rule is posted above.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know how straightforward those rules are. Pls understand that 301 redirect can be done using mod_rewrite and mod_alias both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple simple redirects for which you want to suppress query string values you could put all the redirects in a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/rewritemap.html) (since you already have access to httpd.conf), and have one .htaccess rule that suppresses the query strings as below

**place in htaccess**

```
#if there is a match in the map
RewriteCond ${redirect_map:$1} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${redirect_map:$1}? [R,L]
```

**place in httpd.conf**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap redirect_map txt:/usr/local/apache/conf/redirect.map
```

**contents of /usr/local/apache/conf/redirect.map**
key followed by a space followed by target

```
directory/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/ example/category7/subdirectory/file.html
directory4/subdirectory2/subdirectory9/ example/category5/subdirectory4/file332.html
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have taken a look at the option of a RewriteMap. However, I'm not entirely sure if this solution will work for my situation. The reason is that, the URL's which I need to redirect do not have common "features" to them. So, I wonder if I can use a RewriteMap for simple redirects, similar to how it is done in .htaccess? - Example:

/directory/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/ redirects to http://www.example/category7/subdirectory/file.html

---or---

/directory4/subdirectory2/subdirectory9/ redirects to http://www.example/category5/subdirectory4/file332.html

Make sense?

Comment: @KevinGleeson Simple redirects, and plenty of them, are exactly what RewriteMap is good for. Most people don't use it because they are on shared hosting without access to httpd.conf.

Comment: Thanks again and I think we are getting close to a solution. When I do exactly as described above, for directories which are not specified in the map, I am getting a server error. Is it possible for URL's which do not exist in the map, to keep the original URL structure?

Comment: @KevinGleeson Yes, specify a default as the original URl, which I added above as what comes after the `|` i.e. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${redirect_map:$1|$1}? [R,L]`.

Answer (score 0):

That's what your rule has defined it to do:

```
RewriteRule ^(.)(/./d/[^.]*)$ /category/refine.cgi\?\&a\=$2
```

It says to create a URL that will look like:
category/refine.cgi?&a=/foo/bar/

If you don't want that to happen, change your rule to be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.)(/./d/[^.]*)$ /category/refine.cgi\?
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Duncan. My only concern is that the rule will then not perform as intended. While that edit may prevent the query from being appended to the end of the URL which has been 301 redirected in .htaccess, it may also prevent the queries being passed through for URL's which have not been redirected through htaccess?

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually want to do a 301 redirect then